# python import inside function hides existing variable

Tags: python, python-import

I was wrestling with a weird "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" issue in a multi-submodule project I am working on and slimmed it down to this snippet (using the logging module from standard library):

```
import logging

def foo():
    logging.info('foo')

def bar():
    logging.info('bar')
    if False:
        import logging.handlers
        # With these alternatives things work:
        # import logging.handlers as logginghandlers
        # from logging.handlers import SocketHandler

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
foo()
bar()
```

Which has this output (I tried python 2.7 and 3.3):

```
INFO:root:foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import-test01.py", line 16, in <module>
    bar()
  File "import-test01.py", line 7, in bar
    logging.info('bar')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logging' referenced before assignment
```

Apparently the presence of an import statement inside a function hides already existing variables with the same name in the function scope, even if the import is not executed.

This feels counter-intuitive and non-pythonic. I tried to find some information or documentation about this, without much success thus far. Has someone more information/insights about this behaviour?

thanks

Comment: One Way to deal with masking issue is by using 'as' when importing....
if False: import logging.handlers as handler

Comment: @Stefaan It looks like good reason to follow the [PEP 008 advice on imports](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): "Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants."
I know, there are often reasons to break the rules (at your own risk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is just a restatement of the same ol' way python deals with locals masking globals.

to understand it, `import foo` is (approximately) syntactic sugar for:

```
foo = __import__("foo")
```

thus, your code is:

```
x = 1
def bar():
    print x
    if False:
        x = 2
```

since the name `logging` appears on the left side of an assignment statement *inside bar*, it is taken to be a local variable reference, and so python won't look for a global by the same name in that scope, even though the line that sets it can never be called.

The usual workarounds for dealing with globals apply: use another name, as you have found, or:

```
def bar():
    global logging
    logging.info('bar')
    if False:
        import logging.handlers
```

so that python won't think `logging` is local.

Answer (score 1):

By that `import` statement you introduce `logging` as a local variable in the function and you call that local variable before it's initialized.

```
def bar():
    import logging.handlers
    print locals()

>>> foo()
{'logging': <module 'logging' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>}
```

Comment: Indeed, but it's only in `locals()` after execution of the import statement, which is totally as expected.

My problem is that "logging" is **not** in `locals()` before the import statement (not necessarily to be executed), it is in `globals()`, and still I get `UnboundLocalError`, as if was a still undefined local variable.

Comment: oh I see, I considered it as a common knowledge: Python compiles a function before its execution and there's a tuple for all local variables presented in that function. So when it tries to reach for that variable into this tuple it's not there yet -> UnboundLocalError

Comment: Yeah, with IfLoop's answer (about an import being equivalent with a local variable assignment) I now understand what you mean, thanks.