# Strange error of local variable 'SO' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

For unknown reason I getting an error in my Django based app

The error is in my view in line

> post = get_object_or_404(SO, pk=pk)

I am getting this error

> local variable 'SO' referenced before assignment

despite having in header  `from sales.models import SO`

I am accessing SO in other views in the same file without any issue I have this error only in this view and it makes me crazy.

Any ideas?

```
def SO_edit(request,pk,uri):
    uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)

    post = get_object_or_404(SO, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SOForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            SO = form.save(commit=False)
            SO.creation_time = timezone.now()
            SO.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, SO.id + "-SUCCESS Object saved sucssefully")
            return redirect(uri)
    else:
        form = SOForm(instance=post)
        #form.UOM.queryset = UOM.objects.filter(id=pk)
        #form.fields['UOM'].queryset = UOM.objects.filter(product=post.product)

    product = post.company   
    return render(request, 'sales/SO_edit.html', {'form': form, 'product':product })
```

Comment: I don't know what's the problem because there might be other things that mess this up, but you had some bad programming practice, you kept overriding the variable here and there, like you reuse the variable `SO` when you do `SO = form.save(commit=False)`, that might cause your `SO` to refer to the wrong stuff later on.

Comment: @Shang you absolutely correct . Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24307520/105043 has a nice explanation of what's going on